# Is writing to tape drives any different? (Plain C and Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, c

I understand that writing to tape (say floppy) drives using plain C (say the openf statement and subsequent standard C file-write functions) is fundamentally different than writing to regular hard drives. I understand that I have to be careful about what block sizes I use, etc. Can some C veteran confirm that I am right? If I'm right, some further info would be appreciated, such as how I determine the right block size at run-time, etc.

**And for Objective-C programmers:** Do the Foundation classes to write files abstract away such details in that I can just stop worrying about what kind of a physical media I'm writing to? I.e., do the, say, NSFileManager methods support tape drives without me having to worry about anything?

**Note:** I am writing a modern Mac app. However, even though tape drives are rare these days (right?), it seems imprudent to just assume them away. Agreed? If this is the case, and Foundation abstracts such details away (which I hope it does), I should much rather prefer Foundation over plain C, right?

Comment: First make sure you know what kind of tape drive you're dealing with.  The standard old-fashioned type had essentially an unlimited (and variable) block length, while some "smart" drives operate (or used to -- haven't seen any tape drive for maybe eight years) on fixed blocks sizes.

Comment: are you writing backup software? Otherwise, don't worry about tape drives, especially on mac. I don't even know of any that's supported anymore.

Comment: @LordT, No I'm not writing backup software. I just wanted to be 100% sure that I'm supporting every drive out there. Who knows, maybe one day, some weird user comes along with a tape drive... :S

Comment: Tape drives are funny.  Floppy disks are basically like slow regular disks with only one partition.

Comment: @Enchilada: You're worrying too much. Ship the thing and if there's a user out there who needs it to work with a tape, *they* can tell you what tape drive, and maybe even how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openf`? What OS is this? I always just used `open`, `read`, `write`, and `close` for writing to tape for the most part. I think there's some `ioctl` commands to do seeks, and they take a while, but that was it.

As for floppies, they have always just looked like small volumes without a partition map. `vfat` was the usual Linux volume type, IIRC. Nothing special about accessing them.

P.S. I can honestly say that, unless you need a tape drive, you **can** assume them away at this point. I got rid of my last one years ago, and at work the sysadmin only uses a few specialized programs (`tar`, `mt`, etc.) with them, and it's all scripted. **Nobody** uses tapes as secondary storage these days.

Further, I use hard drives, a la Time Machine, as backups these days. They are *far* faster and more cost effective.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant open, not openf. (I'm a bit rusty on my plain C.) Although you're probably right, i.e. that I shouldn't be worrying about this, it would still be nice to know if Foundation automatically takes care of tape drives. Or maybe Mac OS X simply rejects such devices these days? Hmm...

Comment: In general, things like Foundation *should not care*. It's part of the modularization of code, and the Unix philosophy of making everything look like a file with the same `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, and `ioctl` interface. So, unless there's something special your program *can* do with tape drives, *don't do anything.* Let the user use commands like `mt` or `dd` to take care of the details of their drive. They'll have more tools and no more of how it works than you can, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the unix concept of filesystems goes all the way to tape drives. Normally, tapedrives are accessed in a completely different manner (using special programs) than mountable media. Foundation will probably help you with mountable media, but not with tape drives that are anyway just used for backup.
A little googleing on tape drives for mac turns up this: [LTO4 Tape Archiving on the Mac](http://www.studiodaily.com/main/work/LTO4-Tape-Archiving-on-the-Mac_11294.html) - and it's from 2009. I haven't found any info about tape drives in snow leopard or lion. 
So really, I wonder how you would got about accessing one if you can't even test your code.

Comment: Tape drives aren't handled by filesystems. They generally are made to look like a stream of bytes, i.e. a big file with really bad seek times. Usually, there are a series of device files for one drive, each of which is a different combination of options. For example, the default device file will rewind the tape after being closed, but if the low bit of the device file's minor ID is set, it will leave the tape where it is. The user figures out what they want one, chooses the proper device file, and passes that to the program; the program needs to know none of this.